# Can't get libcurl libraries to compile with C program

Tags: c, curl, linker, network-programming, libcurl

I apologize if this kind of question has been asked before but I'm losing my mind over this, I'm rather new to using libraries with C and trying to figure out how to compile a C program with libcurl. The C program is literally just the example code from the libcurl website here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html. So far I've tried compiling it using 
`gcc -I{directory of /curl-7.67.0-win64-mingw/include} -L{directory of /curl-7.67.0-win64-mingw/lib} -llibcurl.a curl.c`
as well as variants on the libcurl name such as `libcurl` without the .a and also just `curl.a` and `curl`. It continuously gives me the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WILLOC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMzPQvE.o:curl.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I understand it I should be able to link the .a file using -L and -l. What am I doing wrong? Is it that I don't have external dependencies that libcurl depends on?

Comment: i think you need to fix  `-llibcurl.a` to `-lcurl`

Comment: @Alex Nikifirov Tried this already. Gives me the same error.

Comment: You [build with a static lib on Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Link_errors_when_building_libcur).

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg Thank you for your reply, but to be honest this is only causing me more confusion. Is a run-time library the same thing as a dynamic library? If so, why do I need to link to a run-time library if I'm using the static library version of libcurl (the .a file)? I created a makefile that sets the CFLAGS to -DCURL_STATICLIB, along with the -I and -L flags, and yet it's still giving me the same error.